# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Last\login_tools.php on line 28

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando hacer un login desde esta pagina:

LOGIN.PHP

```
<?php
# Set page title and display header section.
# Open database connection.
require ( 'includes/connect_db.php' ) ;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <title>Webflix</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="logo">Webflix</h2>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#"  class="active">Home</a>
                    <a href="movies.php">Movies</a>
                    <a href="tvshows.php">TV Shows</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">User
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                            <a href="#">Register</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="login">
                <div class="container">
                    <h3 class="title">Login</h3>
                    <div class="description">
                        <form action="login_action.php" class="form was-validated" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" required>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" id="submitBtn">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Los datos obtenidos del formulario de login pasa a esta otra pagina:

LOGIN_ACTION.PHP

```
<?php # PROCESS LOGIN ATTEMPT.

# Check form submitted.
if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' )
{
  # Open database connection.
  require ( 'includes/connect_db.php' ) ;
  global $link;

  # Get connection, load, and validate functions.
  require ( 'login_tools.php' );

  $email = $_POST[ "email" ];
  $pass =  $_POST[ "pass" ] ;

  # Check login.
  list ( $check, $data ) = validate ( $link, $email, $pass) ;

  # On success set session data and display logged in page.
  if ( $check )  
  {
    # Access session.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ 'userID' ] = $data[ 'userID' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'firstname' ] = $data[ 'firstname' ] ;
    $_SESSION[ 'surname' ] = $data[ 'surname' ] ;
    load ( 'index.php' ) ;
  }
  # Or on failure set errors.
  else { $errors = $data; } 

  # Close database connection.
  mysqli_close( $link ) ; 
}

# Continue to display login page on failure.
include ( 'login.php' ) ;

?>
```

A su vez, para validad que los campos no estan en blanco y realizar el query a la base de datos, los parametros se pasan a la siguiente pagina:

LOGIN_TOOLS.PHP

```
<?php # LOGIN HELPER FUNCTIONS.

# Function to load specified or default URL.
function load( $page = 'login.php' )
{
  # Begin URL with protocol, domain, and current directory.
  $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ) ;

  # Remove trailing slashes then append page name to URL.
  $url = rtrim( $url, '/\\' ) ;
  $url .= '/' . $page ;

  # Execute redirect then quit. 
  header( "Location: $url" ) ; 
  exit() ;
}

# Function to check email address and password. 
function validate( $link, $email = '', $pwd = '')
{

  # Initialize errors array.
  $errors = array() ; 

  # Check email field.
  if ( empty( $email ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.' ; } 
  else  { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, trim( $email ) ) ; }

  # Check password field.
  if ( empty( $pwd ) ) 
  { $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; } 
  else { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link, trim( $pwd ) ) ; }

  # On success retrieve user_id, first_name, and last name from 'users' database.
  if ( empty( $errors ) ) 
  {
    $q = "SELECT userID, firstname, surname FROM user WHERE email='$e' AND pass='$p'" ;  
    $r = mysqli_query ( $link, $q ) ;
    if ( @mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 ) 
    {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
      return array( true, $row ) ; 
    }
    # Or on failure set error message.
    else { $errors[] = 'Email address and password not found.' ; }
  }
  # On failure retrieve error message/s.
  return array( false, $errors ) ; 
}
```

Lo he intentado de diversas maneras, pero al final siempre obtengo el mismo error:

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Last\login_tools.php on line 28

Asi que creo que el error esta en la conexion en la base de datos, pero a la cual despues de mirar muchos tutoriales, creo que esta correcto:

CONNECT_DB.PHP

```
<?php
function OpenCon()
 {
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "";
 $db = "test";

 $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
 
 if(!$link) {
    die("Connect failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 return $link;
 }
 
function CloseCon($link)
 {
 $link -> close();
 }
   
?>
```

Tienen alguna idea de que puede estar ocurriendo?

Muchisimas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136309/discussion-on-question-by-francisco-jose-bejarano-escano-warning-mysqli-real-es).

Answer (score 0):

se esta quedando que esta recibiendo un parámetro NULL, ponele antes de esta línea unos dumps para asegurarte de que la data llegue

```
var_dump($link);
var_dump($email);
exit;
list ( $check, $data ) = validate ( $link, $email, $pass);
```

Saludos